# CSS calc() not working

Tags: css

Is there a limit to how many operands you can have within a CSS `calc()` function?

This works:

```css
div {
    left:calc((100%/54)*26);
    left:-webkit-calc((100%/54)*26);
}
```

This does NOT work:

```css
div {
    left:calc(((100%/54)*14)-140px);
    left:-webkit-calc(((100%/54)*14)-140px);
}
```

Of course, the latter is what I need, because I need to offset a few pixels, but as soon as I try to do that, the value seems to just go to zero.  Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 106, accepted):

To quote [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc)

> The `+` and `-` operators must always be surrounded by whitespace. The
>   operand of `calc(50% -8px)` for instance will be parsed as a percentage
>   followed by a negative length, an invalid expression, while the
>   operand of `calc(50% - 8px)` is a percentage followed by a minus sign
>   and a length. The `*` and `/` operators do not require whitespace, but
>   adding it for consistency is allowed, and recommended.

Space your stuff out, and it will probably work.