# -webkit-calc doesn't work for min-height

Tags: html, css

I am trying this:

```css
.main{
            min-height: -moz-calc(100% -50px);
      min-height: -webkit-calc(100% -50px);
      min-height: calc(100% -50px);
   background-color:#000;
   color:white;
    }

html{
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body style='height:100%;'>
      <header style='height:50px;background-color:#0e0'></header>
      <div class="main">ok</div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

But it doesn't work

I want my div to go to the bottom of screen minus the header that is 50px

Thanks

Comment: Please share your worked example on a fiddle

Comment: calc(100% -50px); - to  calc(100% - 50px);

Comment: so this can be marked as a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967421/css-calc-not-working

Answer (score 1):

`height: 100%` can work if all ancestors of `.main` have the same height defined but in your example the `html` element has not defined any height.

Example #1 (height set on `html` element):  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdrYqx

---

You could try also `vh` units: this won't require to set the height also on the ancestors

```
.main{
    min-height: -moz-calc(100vh - 50px);
    min-height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 50px);
    min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

Example #2: (no height, only `vh` unit):  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJrdeB

Comment: It doesn't work neither

Comment: Why it doesn't work on my snippet then, and neither on my site (I have already set html to 100%

Comment: I see you have updated your question: then I suppose it's due to the missing space after the minus (`-`) as suggested in a comment above. If it still doesn't work the show us a link where the issue occurs

Comment: Aw That was the space, thanks